# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setClipToOutline(boolean)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have the following error in Java code and cause my application to crash. This error is due to the `imageView` being null.

> Error:Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.setClipToOutline(boolean)' on a null object
>   reference at
>   ir.nasim_velayat.sorud.activity.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:91)

And Java Codes:

```
Line 90 : imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_news_top);
Line 91 : imageView.setClipToOutline(true);
```

I anticipate that this error is due to the fact that I have not set the `imageView` correctly, but I do not know how to set it correctly.

xml Code(ImageView):

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_news_top"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_header"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_radius"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have initialized wrong imageview.

```
Please check your R.id.img_news_top.
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand the problem. I used objects of an irrelevant layer in main activity.